# How to apply android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to a single layout

Tags: android

I have two layouts in an activity and i want to apply

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to a single layout and the other layout should not want to be changed when keyboard appears.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I got it,
It can be done by comparing the heights between the edittext. That is by using marginTop property.